# Installation failed to finalize session... Signatures are inconsistent - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to run my project but I get this error:

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl1841863905.tmp/11_app-debug
>   signatures are inconsistent. It is possible that this issue is
>   resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is
>   present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

If I press yes, after some seconds it just shows the same error. I tried to manually delete the application but the application is already deleted from my phone.

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: Turning off instant run eliminates that error.

Comment: i have a same issue when i delete BUILD folder its work for me

Answer (score 199):

This error usually happens to me in Android Studio when I try to open a project that was moved from another path or location, also other circumstances might cause this, what works for me is:

- menu "Build"
- run "Rebuild Project".

Then run app on device or emulator, and error goes away. I know the error has nothing to do with this but that's what fixes it for me, try and let me know.

Comment: This indeed works even when you change your app signature by signing it with different key. After Clean and Rebuild you will get one more error message in AS, but after clicking OK,  the app is correctly installed.

Comment: Works also for `Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl.....tmp/11_app-debug package android inconsistent with .....
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.`

Comment: That's the best answer!

Comment: It really worked for me as well. Thanks. Also thanks google and stackoverflow for bringing this page up for me. I don't appreciate stackoverflow for not allowing me open my own questions.

Comment: This also worked for me where I replaced the default debug keystore with a different one and the Instant Run started not working (throwing inconsistent signature all the time). Rebuilding and possibly invalidate cache and restart Android Studio solved the problem

Answer (score 13):

Am also faced same problem. It can be solved.Delete the below mentioned directories and restart AndroidStudio.Run the application.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Disable the Instant run in Android Studio and then Clean,Rebuild and Run ,It should fix this issue.

Comment: This one helped me, I was facing this issue while running my app on my device: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Missing existing base package for com.mypackage...

Answer (score 9):

Solution: Disable Instant Run

Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Uncheck Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy

My issues was specifically related to a package inconsistency:

`Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdel334040403.tmp/11_package_name_--dev package com.package.name inconsistent with com.package.othername
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling...`

Nope, not true. There was nothing to uninstall. Nothing worked. Cleaning, Invalidate Cache/Restart, deleting folders, .gradlew, restarting the device, unplugging things, etc...

Also as a tip to everyone, when you're making your package name for a project, save yourself the troubles I've had and DO NOT CHANGE IT. It's a unique identifier for your app in the play store. It's used in a lot of cloud messaging identification and deeplinking for package names.

`Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6`

Answer (score 5):

**Disable Instant run in Android Studio**. Then Clean, Rebuild and Run. It should fix this issue.

> **To disable Instant run**, do:
>
> In Android Studio: *Preferences* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → **Uncheck** *Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy*.

Answer (score 4):

I use flavor because I need publish 2 version(Person, Enterprise).

I got the same problem.
My solve is write versionCode android versionName in build.gradle.(before it's in the AndroidManifest.xml).

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Exactly my problem! I was already defining the versions in gradle, but I forgot to remove it from Manifest. Thanks =]

Answer (score 4):

In **Android Studio** from build menu:

```
1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild Project
```

This solved the same issue for me...

Answer (score 2):

I was do this and solved it:

I uninstall MyAPP.apk,and I can't install right now.
so,I install a MyAPP.apk by hand.

Now,I try to retry with Android Studio,and its worked for me.

if you face this bug,try this method ,maybe work for you too.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the Instant run in Android Studio.
1-Go to Settings.
2-Select Build,Execution,Deployment-->Instant Run-->uncheck Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy.

And then Clean,Rebuild and Run ,It should fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after copying an existing app. This helped:

1. Go to project folder, navigate to `build.gradle`
   Under (module:app).
2. click the `build.gradle`, check under `defaultConfig`,
   change the applicationId if it still refers to the original project you copied.
3. Then go to, `Tools > Android > Sync` Project

That worked for me. If it doesn't proceed to the `AndroidManifest` xml and change the label to the string resource for the new app name.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by doing:

1. unplug device
2. adb kill-server
3. adb start-server
4. plug device
5. Run the app from a virtual device

Comment: Doesn't work. Tested with Android 5.0 and ADB 1.0.39.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after adding a signing config.

Solved it by deleting the build folder::

1. Project view -> app -> build
   (delete this folder or all the folders under it)
2. Clean project
3. Rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

in my case after Rebuild Project worked :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had added **extra blank line** after versionCode line. 
I kept getting version inconsistent issue. It finally went off after removing extra blank line and syncing again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you after updating my Windows 10.
What I did to make it work, was to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to restart my phone to get it to work (the app was uninstalled when I restarted my phone).

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml you should add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` above `<application ... />`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting all old applications from the target device.
Give it a try once you are using the single device to deploy all your applications.

I could not find **Uncheck Enable Instant Run** option in my android studio 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

1. Build-> Rebuild Project.
2. Clean.
3. Run
   Specifically, It worked for me.
   Hopefully, the problem will solve.