# Signing The App Bundle Base Module And Dynamic Feature Module

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

In the Google official guide for App Bundle: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure#base_build_config it said that signing information only needs to be specified in the base module build.config file. The dynamic module signing info goes with base module.

I am using my own keystore file, so I only include the signingConfig in the base module. However, when I build and run the app on a device, it always pop up the error:

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK:
>   /data/app/vmdl538875391.tmp/1_feature_-debug signatures are
>   inconsistent. It is possible that this issue is resolved by
>   uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then
>   re-installing.

When I include the signing info in the dynamic module, the error goes away.
So does this conflict with the official guide? Or did I do anything incorrect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a setting in Edit Configuration.. In order to only include signing info in the base module of a bundle, I need to choose 'APK from app bundle', not the 'default APK'. Otherwise, Android Studio will use the signing info to sign the APK instead of the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

1. **menu "Build"**
2. **run "Rebuild Project".**

Then run app on device or emulator

or if the above solution doesn't work.

Then try this

Disable the **Instant run** in Android Studio and then **Clean, Rebuild and Run**, It should fix this issue.

Comment: I've searched this error before I posted the question, and tried everything you mentioned but they are not working. I've managed to let the error disappear by adding signature configuration in the dynamic module. However, the android official guide said only to include signature information in the base module..

Comment: have you tried all the solutions from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668595/installation-failed-to-finalize-session-signatures-are-inconsistent-android

Comment: The problem is caused by a setting in EditConfiguration.. In order to only include signing info in the base module of a bundle, I need to choose 'APK from app bundle', not the 'default APK'. Otherwise, Android Studio will use the signing info to sign the APK instead of the bundle.